# How come that we can implement call/cc, but the classical logic (intuitionistic + call/cc) is not constructive?

Tags: functional-programming, continuations, callcc, curry-howard

Intuitionistic logic, being constructive, is the basis for type systems in functional programming. The classical logic is not constructive, in particular the law of excluded middle *A ∨ ¬A* (or its equivalents, such as [double negation elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative_elimination) or [Pierce's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law)).

However, we can implement (construct) the [call-with-current-continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) operator (AKA *call/cc*), for example as in [Scheme](http://community.schemewiki.org/?call-with-current-continuation). So why isn't *call/cc* constructive?

Comment: Hm, we indeed can't implement `call/cc` in Scheme itself...It must be implemented from the runtime system, which has direct control over the stack.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that with *call/cc* the result depends on the order of evaluation. Consider the following example in Haskell. Assuming we have the *call/cc* operator

```hs
callcc :: ((a -> b) -> a) -> a
callcc = undefined
```

let's define

```hs
example :: Int
example =
    callcc (\s ->
        callcc (\t ->
            s 3 + t 4
        )
    )
```

Both functions are pure, so the value of `example` should be uniquely determined. However, it depends on the evaluation order. If `s 3` is evaluated first, the result is `3`; if `t 4` is evaluated first, the result is `4`.

This corresponds to two distinct examples in the continuation monad (which enforces order):

```hs
-- the result is 3
example1 :: (MonadCont m) => m Int
example1 =
    callCC (\s ->
        callCC (\t -> do
            x <- s 3
            y <- t 4
            return (x + y)
        )
    )

-- the result is 4
example2 :: (MonadCont m) => m Int
example2 =
    callCC (\s ->
        callCC (\t -> do
            y <- t 4 -- switched order
            x <- s 3
            return (x + y)
        )
    )
```

It even depends on if a term is evaluated at all or not:

```hs
example' :: Int
example' = callcc (\s -> const 1 (s 2))
```

If `s 2` gets evaluated, the result is `2`, otherwise `1`.

This means that the **[Church-Rosser theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Rosser_theorem) doesn't hold** in the presence of *call/cc*. In particular, **terms no longer have unique [normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_normal_form)**.

Perhaps one possibility would be to view *call/cc* as a non-deterministic (non-constructive) operator that combines all the possible results obtained by (not) evaluating different sub-terms in various order. The result of a program would then be the set of all such possible normal forms. However the standard *call/cc* implementation will always pick just one of them (depending on its particular evaluation order).

Comment: I think the type signature corresponding to the law of excluded middle should be
`callcc :: ((a -> Void) -> Void) -> a`